# Show that there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$, such that $b_{n+1} < b_n$.

Tags: number-theory

Let $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+…+\frac{1}{n} = \frac{a_n}{b_n}$,where $a_n$ and $b_n$ are relatively prime. Show that there exist infinitely many positive integers $n$, such that $b_{n+1} < b_n$.

I started to write something like $\frac{a_n}{b_n} + \frac{1}{n+1} = \frac{a_{n+1}}{b_{n+1}}$, and I don’t know how to continue. Maybe I should analyze the factors of n?

Comment: This paper (page 3, section iii) has a simple proof of this fact https://arxiv.org/abs/1607.02863 Look likes it always happens for $n=p(p-1)$ for prime $p$

Comment: @QC_QAOA thanks, this article really answer my questions.